# How to pick colours from a Color palette for non-chart elements?

Tags: reporting-services, color-palette

I'm in the process of developing a report for a client, and we have a specific requirement that we build table of items that are also shown in a chart. The table will have objects in it which are coloured in the same way as the chart (background - kind of like a manually-constructed legend for the chart).

I would like to select colours from the colour palette used for the chart, as that would make it simple (just order the data and it'll come out with the same colours naturally.

Unfortunately, I can't find any way to do this for a table. Is there an expression or something to access palettes that we can put into the background colour expression field? Or another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds complex: find the palette in use, work out what section of the chart these rows are for and colour them accordingly, with the order of the colours changing every time you print the chart.

An easier way would be to enforce consistency of colours for your grouping. For example, let's say you are grouping by department and you want IT to be blue, Finance to be red, HR to be green, and so forth. Now you could do this using a `IIF` or `SWITCH` statement:

```
=Switch(Fields!Dept.Value = "IT", "Blue", Fields!Dept.Value = "Finance", "Red", Fields!Dept.Value = "HR", "Green")
```

However, that gets a bit messy to maintain. It is easier to have a colour field on your department table, then use this in your charts. For example, in bar graphs you do the following:

1. Right click the chart body and choose Properties
2. Click the Data tab
3. In the Values section, click the Edit button
4. Click on the Appearance tab
5. Click the Series Style button
6. Click the Fill tab
7. In the Color text box, put the expression that you want the colour to be. Given that we have this in our department database already, we simply use:

   =Fields!DeptColour.Value

and then our departments are coloured the same on every bar graph.

For line graphs, you have to do the same except this time you put the colour expression in the Color text box on the Border and Line tab on the Series Style dialogue (rather than in the Fill).

Comment: Unfortunately we can't change the database. Funnily enough, it does have a "Colour" field, but they're all a default value. Manually specifying the lists is a no-go, as it's by project (which can be created at any time), not by department or anything static. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: You should look into using the `Colour` field. Otherwise, you could have an XML file as a colour dataset and use `=Lookup(Fields!Dept.Value, Fields!Dept.Value, Fields!Colour.Value, "XMLColourDataset")` to look up your colour value. Or define a colour lookup in a custom DLL that you add to your reports.