# How to Group Multiple Datasets in Pie Chart Legend?

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart

I currently have a pie chart that is taking from a dataset 1 and displaying the result rows.

What I would like to add is a second and third dataset, dataset 2 and dataset 3, to add to the legend of the pie chart, but not the actual displayed chart.

Example:
Dataset 1 contains apples 50% and oranges 50%
Dataset 2 contains different apples adding up to 50%
Dataset 3 contains different oranges adding up to 50%.

Picture of intended output:

[image: Oranges and Apples pie chart with nested dataset legend]

Is there a way to modify that legend to allow different datasets to not impact the pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the legend, size the chart so it is on one side of the report and put a table on the other side. The table becomes the legend replacement and is just a normal report with grouping on Apples and Oranges and detail rows of their different types.

You may want to manually set the colouring of the chart sections and display those colours in the table if you want it to look like an actual legend. I discuss an easy way to do this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268046/how-to-pick-colours-from-a-color-palette-for-non-chart-elements/17268810#17268810).

Comment: Thanks! I also found you can use the lookup function in a category group label, which can reference the other dataset amounts without impacting the chart, although I had to use VBCRLF to orient the data to the color key. :)